# Using WAN IP to connect to a device connected to router

Tags: ip, router, lan, wan

I have a router (belkin) with many devices connected.

I ran a application on one my devices and the application assigned a port number for remote connection.

Now for me access this device i tried doing something like:

```
wanipaddress:port
```

But unable to connect. I am not sure if the router can be used to accomplish the  above.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the above?

P.S my router assigned unique LAN IP to all the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the following using Port Forwarding mechanism. A port forward is a way of making a computer on your home or business network accessible to computers on the internet, even though they are behind a router.

I found the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAbM0CnZzp4) to be useful: